# Make paragraph padding only affect text inside

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement to have the following situation in htmls

```
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
    <img src=http://cdn-img.health.com/sites/default/files/styles/400x400/public/styles/400x400/public/styles/main/public/how-take-care-cat-400x400.jpg?itok=ta2kPB58>
</p>
```

I need to display image in full width but should have some padding for text.

How can I style these scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure your <p> tag is written as <p> not <p !!!

Comment: I think you specified your topic in reverse order

Comment: Remember to use '/' in closing tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure, what you mean, but I figured something like this:

Basically you give a `padding` to the `<p>` and remove it using a nagtive `margin` for the `<img>`.
As `width` is relative to the parent element's content-box, we have to correct the `width` of the `<img>` a little.

```css
img {
  width: calc( 100% + 6em );
  margin: auto -3em;
}
p{
  padding: 3em;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
  <br>
  <img src=http://cdn-img.health.com/sites/default/files/styles/400x400/public/styles/400x400/public/styles/main/public/how-take-care-cat-400x400.jpg?itok=ta2kPB58>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you HTML markup is correct before doing other things like adding CSS.

**Your HTML can be something like:**

```
<p class="content">
   <span class="text">Text Goes Here</div>
   <img class="image" src="image-url" />
</p>
```

**CSS**

Now add **padding** to `.text` class

```
.text{
padding:10px; /* This can be any value of your choice*/
display:block; /* Made it block since span is inline by default */
}

.image{
  width:100%;
}
```

**Note:** *Its always a good practice to add class / id to HTML elements*

Answer (score 0):

add in css

```
p img{padding:4px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set img style with margin negative value. Set same value with your parent padding but in negative values.

```css
p {
  padding:20px;
  background:#aaa;
 }

p img {
  margin:-20px;
 }
```

```html
 <p>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
    <img src=http://cdn-img.health.com/sites/default/files/styles/400x400/public/styles/400x400/public/styles/main/public/how-take-care-cat-400x400.jpg?itok=ta2kPB58>
<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
img {
  width: 100% ;
}
p{
  padding: 3em;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/902x12qe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move the text a bit inside without affecting the image you can use

```css
p{text-indent:10px;vertical-align: top; margin-top: 10px}
img{margin:10px;}
```

```html
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
    <img src=http://cdn-img.health.com/sites/default/files/styles/400x400/public/styles/400x400/public/styles/main/public/how-take-care-cat-400x400.jpg?itok=ta2kPB58>
<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this:

```html
<html>
<style>
span {
    background-color: #808080;
}
</style>
<p><span>sometext<span></p>
<html>
```